# Is there any interface PagingAndSortingRepository in firestore to handle the pagination similar to Spring Data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, pagination, reactive-programming

I want to do the pagination in Firestore using the rest API's (using springboot). Is there any way similar to spring data?

Currently I am using the Paginate data with query cursors. But here we will require the last element (last token/last count) or last snapshot to get the next batch.

Is there any other way to paginate using just page and page size in Firestore?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, Firestore's pagination was design with a query cursor approach in mind.

Even if there were to exist a library that does this under the hood and gives you an illusion of a page/pagesize approach, which I don't think there is, it won't matter since you are using the REST API to connect to Firestore, so you should use the parameters that Firestore was designed to accept which are, as you mentioned, the last element(last token/last count) or last snapshot to get the next batch.